# Using a whole sentence as a subject

Tags: subordinate-clauses, complementation

I read this following sentences on a newspaper and I cannot understand the second sentence's structure.

> He added: 'We have all had moments where a smell can take you back
>   somewhere in time. **That the victim could identify this smell
>   provided us with another piece in the puzzle.'**

What I see is that a sentence, "the victim could identify this smell", is used as a subject of another sentence. For me it sounds wrong and it should be noun phrase. For example it could have been:

> The victim's identification of the smell provided us with another piece in
>   the puzzle.

or there could have been a "so that it"

> the victim could identify this smell so  that it provided us with
>   another piece in the puzzle.

Comment: Well, this is a correct construction. I'm not sure how to justify it, though.

Comment: I love questions like this, because they force me to think about sentences that are plainly right, but *why* they are right isn't immediately obvious.

Answer (score 3):

The *that* which introduces the first clause is technically called a "complementizer": it instructs the hearer/reader to understand what follows as a subordinate clause playing the role of a noun phrase with respect to the verb in the main clause.

In this case the NP acts as Subject of the verb *provided*. You may be more familiar with uses of *that* to mark Objects of the verb, such as

> The police learned [that the victim could identify this smell].
>   The police said [that the victim could identify this smell].

Comment: Thanks, I understand.what do you think of my second sentence? we can omit "so" , if it makes sense, in this case is it still complement clause ?

Comment: @ELL No. With "this smell that provided &c" *that* would be taken as a relative pronoun signalling that what follows should be interpreted with its referent *smell* filling the subject 'gap'. That's a different meaning: it's not the identification but the smell which provides the piece.

Answer (score -1):

To add to StoneyB's answer (which is exactly right), I'd like to add a tip showing how you can informally understand the construction. Let's start with a direct, standard way to under this *that*-clause:

> 1. [ That the victim could identify this smell ] provided us with another piece in the puzzle.

Now, let's consider other possibilities. Your attempt to paraphrase the sentence with *identification* or *so* doesn't really work. The former changes the meaning. The latter even sounds wrong. Here is a better paraphrase. It keeps the original meaning, though it doesn't sound as good as the original:

> 2. **What** provided us with another piece in the puzzle **was that** the victim could identify this smell.

We can understand this paraphrase like this: Something provided us (with another piece in the puzzle). What was it? It was that the victim could identify this smell (that provided us with that).

Comment: ok I gave up on trying to change that-noun clause as a subject sentences.how about this example : The baby was making too much noise that I could not sleep.I think " the baby was making too much noise" is noun-clause but it is not subject.Could you parse this sentence please.It sounds like I could not sleep because the baby was making too much noise..this time that noun-clause may be  a  kind of complement or predicate?

Comment: @ELL That deserves its own question. Also, you may want to check first whether or not your sentence is well-formed. Hint: so/such ... that, too/enough ... to.